# wso2 api manager throws error with key managers

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

wso2 api manager throws error with key managers we facing the below error when browsing key managers from api manager admin

```
{
    "code": 900967,
    "message": "General Error",
    "description": "Server Error Occurred",
}
```

[image]

the below logs from api manager logs

```
[2024-02-24 11:22:42,135] ERROR - KeymanagersApiServiceImpl Error while retrieving key manager configurations
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while Decrypting value
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIAdminImpl.getDecryptedValue_aroundBody44(APIAdminImpl.java:489) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl-9.0.174.130.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIAdminImpl.getDecryptedValue(APIAdminImpl.java:471) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl-9.0.174.130.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIAdminImpl.decryptValue_aroundBody42(APIAdminImpl.java:451) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl-9.0.174.130.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIAdminImpl.decryptValue(APIAdminImpl.java:448) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl-9.0.174.130.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIAdminImpl.decryptKeyManagerConfigurationValues_aroundBody40(APIAdminImpl.java:442) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl-9.0.174.130.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIAdminImpl.decryptKeyManagerConfigurationValues(APIAdminImpl.java:433) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl-9.0.174.130.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIAdminImpl.getKeyManagerConfigurationsByTenant_aroundBody28(APIAdminImpl.java:339) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl-9.0.174.130.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIAdminImpl.getKeyManagerConfigurationsByTenant(APIAdminImpl.java:318) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl-9.0.174.130.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.internal.service.impl.KeymanagersApiServiceImpl.keymanagersGet(KeymanagersApiServiceImpl.java:46) [classes/:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.internal.service.KeymanagersApi.keymanagersGet(KeymanagersApi.java:48) [classes/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor251.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) [cxf-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) [cxf-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) [cxf-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) [cxf-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) [cxf-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:304) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:222) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) [tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.52.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:279) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.4.25.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.4.25.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:104) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.4.25.11.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:101) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.2.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.2.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.2.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.2.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat_9.0.52.wso2v2.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoException: An error occurred while decrypting data.
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoUtil.decrypt(CryptoUtil.java:317) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.2.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIAdminImpl.getDecryptedValue_aroundBody44(APIAdminImpl.java:483) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl-9.0.174.130.jar:?]
        ... 60 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.crypto.api.CryptoException: An error occurred while decrypting using the algorithm : 'RSA/ECB/OAEPwithSHA1andMGF1Padding', and crypto provider : 'org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.KeyStoreBasedInternalCryptoProvider'
        at org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.KeyStoreBasedInternalCryptoProvider.decrypt(KeyStoreBasedInternalCryptoProvider.java:163) ~[org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider_1.1.9.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.crypto.impl.DefaultCryptoService.decrypt(DefaultCryptoService.java:132) ~[org.wso2.carbon.crypto.impl_1.1.9.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoUtil.decrypt(CryptoUtil.java:311) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.2.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIAdminImpl.getDecryptedValue_aroundBody44(APIAdminImpl.java:483) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl-9.0.174.130.jar:?]
        ... 60 more
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.util.BadBlockException: unable to decrypt block
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.getOutput(Unknown Source) ~[bcprov-jdk15on-1.70.jar:1.70.0]
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source) ~[bcprov-jdk15on-1.70.jar:1.70.0]
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2202) ~[?:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.KeyStoreBasedInternalCryptoProvider.decrypt(KeyStoreBasedInternalCryptoProvider.java:152) ~[org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider_1.1.9.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.crypto.impl.DefaultCryptoService.decrypt(DefaultCryptoService.java:132) ~[org.wso2.carbon.crypto.impl_1.1.9.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoUtil.decrypt(CryptoUtil.java:311) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.2.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIAdminImpl.getDecryptedValue_aroundBody44(APIAdminImpl.java:483) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl-9.0.174.130.jar:?]
        ... 60 more
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: data wrong
        at org.bouncycastle.crypto.encodings.OAEPEncoding.decodeBlock(Unknown Source) ~[bcprov-jdk15on-1.70.jar:1.70.0]
        at org.bouncycastle.crypto.encodings.OAEPEncoding.processBlock(Unknown Source) ~[bcprov-jdk15on-1.70.jar:1.70.0]
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.getOutput(Unknown Source) ~[bcprov-jdk15on-1.70.jar:1.70.0]
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source) ~[bcprov-jdk15on-1.70.jar:1.70.0]
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2202) ~[?:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.KeyStoreBasedInternalCryptoProvider.decrypt(KeyStoreBasedInternalCryptoProvider.java:152) ~[org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider_1.1.9.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.crypto.impl.DefaultCryptoService.decrypt(DefaultCryptoService.java:132) ~[org.wso2.carbon.crypto.impl_1.1.9.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoUtil.decrypt(CryptoUtil.java:311) ~[org.wso2.carbon.core_4.6.2.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIAdminImpl.getDecryptedValue_aroundBody44(APIAdminImpl.java:483) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl-9.0.174.130.jar:?]
        ... 60 more
[2024-02-24 11:45:33,757] ERROR - KeyManagersApiServiceImpl Error while retrieving keyManager Details for Tenant carbon.super
[2024-02-24 11:45:34,748] ERROR - GlobalThrowableMapper Error while Decrypting value
[2024-02-24 11:45:46,751]  WARN - TenantInfoApiServiceImpl Could not decode the username. Using original username
[2024-02-24 11:45:47,012] ERROR - GlobalThrowableMapper Error while Decrypting value
```

what is the issue here although it was working fine?

the version of api manager:- WSO2 API-M v4.0.0 integrated with wso2 identity server v6.0.0

Comment: Were there any changes to the Keystores that are configured in the WSO2 APIM and Identity Server?